Use Entity Framework to generate the database into a server (code-first approach)
This is the first time working with the Entity Framework. So I don't know what to do next in order to generate my tables.
I created all the classes that I need to define my tables. In addition to the ProjectContext.cs class:
//using System.Data.Entity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Projet.Models;

namespace Projet
{
    public class ProjetContext : DbContext
    {
        public ProjetContext()
        {
        }

        public ProjetContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }
....
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=;Database=;User Id=;Password=;TrustServerCertificate=True;");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            // ..
        }
    }
}

I tried the add -migration in the terminal (Power Shell), which caused this error :

Add-Migration : The term 'Add-Migration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I got all my packages installed:
Packages installed
(I did try to restart vs and my whole pc.)
I am completely blocked here. I don't want to move on to creating controllers or views until I check the db and the models as I still have some doubts about it.
Any help will be appreciated.

You're using EF Core not EF, so watch out that documentation and tutorials you look up are for EF Core. You need to install/ use the EF Core tools as documented here. You can choose whether you want to use the Visual Studio integrated terminal (Package Manager console) or PowerShell.

I know I am using EF.Core. Did I mess something up in the code ? I seriously don't know where the issue is coming from. I rechecked the versions and packages. Everything is compatible. The other doubt was in using the power shell terminal instead of the nugets terminal but the PowerShell termiinal is where it should be written. Right

You're also using EF6 besides EFC7. I assume you should first remove the EF6 package.

I removed it, and tried all the commands in different consoles. Nothing works ....

Try use PacketManageConsole. For me when using EF core add-migration "MigrationName" worked. Then use update-database to create/update database up to migration.

Use package manager console for EF Core, not PowerShell window
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell
For PS console there is another tool set:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet
